# what is the influence of the specific statistical model selection in a practical project

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, mathematical-modeling

I hope this is the right place to ask this question. But if it is not, please feel free to migrate. There is a famous quote, which is like "all models are wrong, but a few are useful". So, I was just wondering, what is the influence of the model selection in a practical project? For instance, suppose we have two models, one is statistically more precise than the other one. So, the more preciser one should be used instead of the not so precise one? Is this true? Many thanks for your time and attention.

Answer (score 0):

There is almost always a choice to be made between a simple model
that is easy to handle but may not be exactly correct, and a
more complex model that is more nearly correct and less convenient
to deal with.

One example is the famous birthday problem. It is said that
if there are 23
randomly chosen people in a room, there is a little more
than a 50-50 chance that two of them will have the same birthday.
The computation is not difficult if we assume there are
only 365 birthdays (ignoring Feb 29) and that they are
equally likely. We know neither of these assumptions is
exactly correct. (Of course, we also hope the people are
really chosen at random: a convention of twins or a
meeting of the Scorpian Society would be a disaster.)
Through really advanced conbinatorial analysis or fairly
simple computer simulation, one can include Feb 29 and
use actual US birthday frequencies from government records
(roughly speaking summer birthdays are a little more frequent).
Then it turns out that the probabilities of birthday
coincidences are about the same to two decimal places,
but not exactly. In a country where birthdays are very
much more common in some months than others, the results
might be considerably different.

Another example is in the modeling of waiting lines (queues).
One often assumes that the times between arrivals of
customers are distributed according to an exponential
distribution. This is a pretty good model for many purposes
and it is very convenient because the 'no-memory property'
of exponential distributions makes it unnecessary to
consider immediate past history when predicting the
arrival of the next customer. In some situations the
simple exponential model just doesn't work and then
the distribution theory can be quite complicated.

A third example is that the famous normal distribution
(bell curve) is often used to model heights of people, 
sizes of error in scientific measurements, scores
on college entrance exams, and so on.
There are sound theoretical reasons why the normal distribution
is so often useful. But it is rare that the fit is
perfect. (For example, a normal model necessarily includes
a *very tiny* chance of a person with negative height.
Easily ignored, but obviously wrong.)

Unfortunately, real life is very complicated and it is
almost never possible to make an absolutely perfect
model of a chance situation. Hence the quote you
mentioned about all models being wrong, but some useful.
(I believe G.E.P. Box is usually credited with that
quote.)

Comment: thanks very much for your answer. So, generally, how to determine which model is better and which one is not?

Comment: In general, I'd say to pick the simplest model that promises to be useful. I'd try to consider each of the ways it might go wrong and and try to check whether any of those flaws is too serious for the model to be useful. Sometimes you can test assumptions using the data at hand. Sometimes look to see what has happened when the model was used before in a similar situation. With enough data one can test for normality. Often, a simulation study can help; the birthday problem is easy to simulate for nonuniform birthdays. The checking depends on the type of model and source of data.